# Yii ESelect2 extension show preselected valued

Tags: yii, jquery-select2

i want to show already selected values in tags of ESelected extension but unable to find any solution my code in update form in view is

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
        'name' => 'cat_names[]',
        'data' => Coupon::getCategories(),
        'options' => array(
            'placeholder' => '',
            'allowClear' => true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
        ),
    ));
```

if i add tags fields in option of Eselect it changes the behaviour and stop working i add tags in options like this

```
 'tags' => Coupon::getCategories_old(),
```

Any suggestion will be helpfull thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
        'name' => 'cat_names[]',
        'value'=>  array(91,95),
        'data' => Coupon::getCategories(),
        'options' => array(
            'placeholder' => '',
            'allowClear' => true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
        ),
    ));
```